# Switching between applications which are already running

Tags: android

I have 2 application where I can open one from another. i.e The applications are A,B and I have opened A then opening B from A. Now I have A & B opened and I am opening A again from B, at that time B is created as a new Instance. Is there any way where I can bring application B to front which is already running?

Comment: How are you opening one application from another or is it Activity which you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to specify

```
 android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                              "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

in your manifest file, in your case if I get you right you need singleInstance

Comment: Now I have got another issue. I am getting a blank(black) screen during transition between two activities for few seconds after I changed launchMode to singleInstance

Comment: maybe singleTask is the proper for you, I do not know what precisely you want to achieve... try all of them to find the right one :)

Comment: I think this is the right way to open a new app from another

http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/launching-other-application-using-code.html